# set a default page in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

i am trying to set up a  default page for my dynamic data website.. the problem is that its a template

so it would be something like this:  Orders/List.aspx

can anyone please help me out with this..

Thanx

Owais F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Default.aspx page outside of your DynamicData folder as the default and just have that page redirect to the Orders/List.aspx page.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Response.Redirect("Orders/List.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying you want the default page in one directory to take you to a page in another directory?

I don't believe you can do that, rather, you have to have the ASPX page in the directory redirect to the page in the other directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with using a template for your default page. You need to set up the virtual directory properly in IIS. Read [this information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab.aspx), it should help.